# How can I retrieve sections, tabs by using c# from MS dynamics CRM 2016?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm

I can retrieve **attibutes** by using code below:

```
    public static EntityMetadata RetrieveEntityMetadata(IOrganizationService service, string logicalName)
    {

        var request = new RetrieveEntityRequest()
        {
            LogicalName = logicalName,
            EntityFilters = EntityFilters.All,
            RetrieveAsIfPublished = false
        };
        var result = (RetrieveEntityResponse)service.Execute(request);
        return result.EntityMetadata;
    }
```

And `result.EntityMetadata` have a property `Attributes`, which contains all attributes of entity. But I want also get sections list of entity. How can I do this?

Comment: Sections are frontend-stuff, I don't think you can retrieve those with EntityMetadata.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sections and tabs are belongs to the form layout and not to the entity itself. There are different type of forms, and each type can have moe than one instance of the form (In case you'll have more than one main form, which should be taken?).

If you know exactly which form you need, than you should retrieve it as an entity of type `systemform` with field `formxml`, which contains XML template of the form. Parse that XML and you'll get the sections and tabs

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I always need main form of entity, now how to build FormXml? Also by using C#, don't using special plugins like XrmToolbox ets. For example, I chose main form of entity account. What I need to do next?

Comment: Don't forget that there could be **more than one** main form. Just Make a simple `RetrieveMultiple` request (as you are doing for any entity) in `formxml` you'll get an XML that you can parse using [XPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4bektfx9(v=vs.110).aspx)